# Unknown localEntry mediator in WSO2ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am getting this error when using localEntry mediator in WSO2ESB 5.0.0:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Unknown mediator referenced by configuration element : {http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse}localEntry
```

Does this mediator exist? According to this [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sample+8%3A+Introduction+to+Static+and+Dynamic+Registry+Resources+and+Using+XSLT+Transformations) it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local Entry is not a mediator. Its task is to store information. The way you're using it must be wrong.